# How do I analyze the source of the "undefined method `attribute_method_matcher'" error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I get an error when new creating a new class in a Rails Controller.

How can I understand what's happening here? Thanks

```
Error:
NoMethodError in MystudentsController#new

undefined method `attribute_method_matcher' for nil:NilClass  
Rails.root: E:/Nam 4 HK 1/TT CNPM/workspace/lab2

app/controllers/mystudents_controller.rb:27:in `new'
app/controllers/mystudents_controller.rb:27:in `new'
```

And this is function new in `mystudent_controller.rb` file:

```
def new    
  @mystudent = Mystudent.new
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.xml  { render :xml => @mystudents }
  end
end
```

Comment: Mystudent seems to be nil (not defined)
Can you please post your model and your controller in full length?

Comment: Additionally, the line "format.xml  { render :xml => @mystudents }
" need to be changed to "@mystudent" instead of "@mystudents"

Answer (score 5):

I believe that one of your column names in the table is a reserved word.
Look for typical things for a student, class, or something like that...
That would typically trigger this - `**attribute_method_matcher**'

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo there. `@mystudents` needs to be `@mystudent`.

You're getting this error message because the variable `@mystudents` [sic] has never been assigned to and therefore is nil.