# undefined method `attribute_method_matcher' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting this error "undefined method `attribute_method_matcher' for nil:NilClass".

My controller name is Cad Its function is

```
  def index
     @cadempty = Cad.new
     @caddata = Cad.all

  end
```

The error is on creating the new object. If I comment `Cad.new` the code  works fine.

Earlier I thought it could be because  I have a method named 'new' and I was Using `User.new` to create a blank object for the form. But its not the error I renamed the method to something else and the error still exists. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414297/how-do-i-analyze-the-source-of-the-undefined-method-attribute-method-matcher

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe one of your column names in the database table is a reserved word.

> Avoid using names for methods that are reserved words in the language.

Comment: Yeah that was the issue ... Thanks for the help.